# Is there an upper bound on the number of concurrent connections to Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Just what the title indicates, is there an upper limit on the number of concurrent sessions for a Gmail user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gmail support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/97150) indicates that it currently has a limit of 15 simultaneous IMAP connections per account.

> According to the Gmail Terms of Use, each user account is intended for
>   single use. This means that if you have multiple users frequently
>   accessing the same account or more than one IMAP1 client accessing
>   Gmail at the same time, you may reach a connection threshold and
>   receive the error message, 'Too many simultaneous connections.'
>
> Gmail currently has a limit of 15 simultaneous IMAP connections per
>   account

Hope that helps.